# Inverse and neutral element of $G(\circ)$ where $G= \{ f:x \rightarrow y = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d},\ a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R} \ ad-bc=1 \}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G= \{ f:x \rightarrow y = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d},\ ,a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R} \ ad-bc=1 \}$

I need to prove that $G(\circ)$ is a group where the operation $(\circ)$ is the standard composition of functions.

I have already proved closure and the associative law. I'm having trouble with the inverse element and the neutral element.

For the neutral element it's obvious that it's $f_x(x)=x$ but I'm not sure how can I prove this. Can we just guess this, check it and prove it that way? Otherwise I'm getting a system of equations that I wasn't able to solve.

Now for every function $f(x)=\frac{a_1x+b_1}{c_1x+d_1}$ we need to find an inverse function $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{a_2x+b_2}{c_2x+d_2}$ such that $f \circ f^{-1} (x) = x = f^{-1} \circ f (x)$ . This simplifies to:

$$ f^{-1}(\frac{a_1x+b_1}{c_1x+d_1})=\frac{a_1 a_2x + a_2b_1 +b_2c_1x + b_2d_1}{a_1c_2x + b_1c_2 +c_1d_2x +d_1d_2}=x$$

Now we need to find $a_2, \ b_2,\ c_2,\ d_2$ in terms of $a_1,\,b_1,\ c_1,\ d_1$ which turns out to be quite mess. All coeficients in front of $x^2$ need to add to $0$ those in front of $x$ add to $1$ and the rest add up to $0$.

Perhaps there is a simpler way to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=x$ then, for any function $g$, you have $f\circ g=g\circ f=g$. And indeed $f\in G$: just take $a=d=1$ and $b=c=0$.

As far as the inverse is concerned, it is easy to check that, if$$f_{a,b,c,d}(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$ and $ad-bc=1$, then$$f_{d,-b,-c,a}\circ f_{a,b,c,d}=f_{a,b,c,d}\circ f_{d,-b,-c,a}=\operatorname{Id}.$$

Comment: So it's ok to just guess it and then check whether it's in our set?

Comment: Yes, that's ok. But, of course, you could also *compute* the inverse of $f_{a,b,c,d}$ and then check that it is equal to $f_{d,-b,-c,a}$.